# Setting a language cookie to toggle between resx pages

Tags: c#, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie to change the culture and ui culture of my website when the user clicks the toggle button. This is what i have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CurrentLanguage"];
        if (!IsPostBack && cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            if (cookie.Value.IndexOf("en-") >= 0)
            {
               // currently english
                Culture = "fr-CA";
                UICulture = "fr-CA";
            }
            else
            {
            //currently french
            Culture = "en-CA";
            UICulture = "en-CA";
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and also

```
protected void toggle_lang(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Culture.ToString() == "English (Canada)")
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentLanguage");
            cookie.Value = "fr-CA";
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        else 
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentLanguage");
            cookie.Value = "en-CA";
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
```

When the toggle function is executed, the page refreshes but the culture and cultureui do not get updated..

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: try `Culture = GetCultureInfo(your_lang);` insted of `Culture = "en-CA";`
and 
use  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.'CurrentUICulture' insted of 'UICulture'.
I recomend you to use neutral culture this can reslove problem in  future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wanted to see my code, to set the culture and ui culture depending on the cookie, you need to override the InitializeCulture() like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CurrentLanguage"];
        if (!IsPostBack && cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
        {
            if (cookie.Value.ToString() == "en-CA")
            {
               // currently english
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
            else
            {
               //currently french
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA");
                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
        }
    }
```

And to toggle, set a new cookie and refresh, letting the above function take care of setting the page language, like this:

```
protected void toggle_lang(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Culture.ToString() == "English (Canada)")
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentLanguage");
            cookie.Value = "fr-CA";
           Response.SetCookie(cookie);
           Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

        }
        else 
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CurrentLanguage");
            cookie.Value = "en-CA";
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }

    }
```